# Which of these random variables has/have also a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Assume that X has a normal distribution. Considering the following three random variable: $$W=\frac{X}{2}$$ $$Y=X-2$$ $$Z=X^2$$
>   Which of these random variables has/have also a normal distribution?

In my opinion Y and W because Z is not linear, it's the correct way to solve it?

Comment: Yes, linear combinations of normal random variables are also normal variables. And $X^2$ cannot be normal because it is non-negative valued with probability $1$.

Comment: Having an "opinion" and "solving" a problem (your own terms) is not the same. For future questions, please show that you have really worked on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, W and Y have a normal distribution, as you're dealing with functions which are linear.

Z=X^2 requires a bit more thought.
Start with $P(Z<z)=P(X^2<z)=P(-\sqrt z<X<\sqrt z)=Φ(\sqrt z)-Φ(-\sqrt z)=2Φ(\sqrt z)-1.$
Thus, $f_z(z)=2Φ(\sqrt z)(0.5 z^{-0.5})$, just differentiate using the chain rule. 
After you plug everything into the equation, you get $f_z(z)=\frac{(0.5)^{0.5 }z^{-0.5}e^\frac{-z}{2}}{\sqrt(\pi)}$, which after some thought you might recognise as a Gamma distribution with parameters 0.5 and 0.5. 
Therefore no. 
A very similar calculation for a normal distribution which isn't the standard normal gives you similar result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: This is not necessary, the facts that $P(Z<0)=0$ and that the distribution of $Z$ is not a Dirac mass, suffice.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution),

> If $Z$ is a standard normal deviate, then $X = \sigma Z + \mu  $ will have a normal distribution with expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

This implies that any stretch or translation of Z will still be a normal distribution.
Also:

> The square of $\frac{X}{\sigma}$ has the noncentral chi-squared distribution